# Parsing date and time, try-catch, variable for hours out of scope

Tags: c#, date, parsing, time

I want to parse date and time. I want to catch if there is a format exception and I do the following:

```
    try
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong date and time format!");
    }
```

However when I start working with the value 'time' C# says that "The name 'time' does not exist in the current context". Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've only declared `time` within the `try` block, so it's out of scope after that. You could declare it beforehand:

```
DateTime time;
try
{
    time = ...;
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong date and time format!");
    return; // Or some other way of getting out of the method,
            // otherwise time won't be definitely assigned afterwards
}
```

However, it would be better to use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse) instead of catching the `FormatException`:

```
DateTime time;
if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out time)
{
    // Use time
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong date and time format!");
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks a lo!